# Why does a Gatsby Cloud build triggered by my airtable webhook refresh my index page of listings correctly, but fails to generate new pages?

Tags: gatsby, airtable, gatsby-cloud

I am having a strange issue where I am not seeing Gatsby Cloud generate pages on a cloud build, only when I manually trigger a full build.

In particular, I have an events calendar backed by Airtable. I use gatsby-source-airtable to pull those events into my site, and a webhook in Airtable to trigger a cloud build when an event is published.

My overview page is generated fine—if I add an event, the build that results includes the new event on the page that lists all upcoming events (https://redemmas.org/events/)

But those builds will regularly fail to generate the single event listing page, i.e. a page like https://redemmas.org/events/scott-branson-presents-practical-anarchism-a-guide-for-daily-life-in-conversation-w-naomi-rose-weintraub-and-danie-black/, which I can only generate by manually triggering a full build.

The src of the events page: https://github.com/johm/redemmas-gatsby/blob/main/src/pages/events.js

The src of the event pages: https://github.com/johm/redemmas-gatsby/blob/main/src/pages/events/%7BAirtable.data__Slug%7D.js

I expect a cloud build on Gatsby Cloud to create new event pages, but it doesn't. There are no errors in the logs.